# Check whether the check box is checked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

**Activity A** has a `listView` , **Activity B** has a `checkBox` and save `button`.

When save `button` in **B** is clicked, it will return to Activity A. When the list in Activity A is pressed, how to show the `check box` is checked in **Activity B** if it is checked before return to **A** ?

**Activity B**

```
 if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)  // when Activity A list is pressed
        {
          final String from = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
          travelFrom.setText(from);
          // how to show check box is checked ? 
         }

      save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // if save button clicked, return from and outstation to A

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             String from=travelFrom.getText().toString(); 
             returnIntent.putExtra("from", from);
             if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
             returnIntent.putExtra("outstation", checkbox.getText().toString()); 
              }
            }
          });
```

**Activity A**

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if listView is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;
                Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults) o;
                String from=fullObject.getFrom();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(),B.class);
                i.putExtra("from",from);
               startActivityForResult(i, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
               }
           });


      @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    from=data.getStringExtra("from");
                    check=data.getStringExtra("outstation");
                    objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(from,check); // save from and "outstation" into MySQL
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

When I press the list in A to B, the check box always not checked. How to make it check ?

Comment: Just to let me get clear about what you want is. You have list in ActivityA (items like A B C D )and onClick on C item you start ActivityB and get result from ActivityB is check or not and update the same status in ActivityA... Right?

Comment: @bharat I have check box in activity B. When return to A and press the list to B again, how can I show the check box is checked ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the relationship between the checkboxes and the list items. You can return any serialized data from activity B through the result intent back to A. If you would like to sync the checked positions, you need to save that data in activity A every time you return from B and pass it back in when you start B

Comment: @cricket_007 Sir, the list item did not contains any check box. I just want when list pressed, it will shows the check box is checked in B if it is checked before return to A. Otherwise, the check box will not be checked if it does not check before return to A

Comment: I understand that the listview contains no checkboxes. That wasn't what I said. Basically, every time you start activity B, there are no boxes checked, yes? Because the activity is reloaded with a clean layout.

Comment: @cricket_007 what is the way to solve ? How can I sync the checked position and add it into `onItemClickListener` ListView A ?

Comment: I **don't know** what you are asking. You haven't explained how the checkboxes have anything to do with the positions (?) of the items in the list. All I can see is that clicking on any list item starts Activity B. After that, I can't tell what you want in Activity B. Isn't there a `setChecked` method on Checkbox class?

Comment: Sir can we move to chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103406/discussion-between-john-joe-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some object with this...

```
class MyData {

    private boolean check;

    public boolean getCheck() { return check; }

}
```

Here is some rough ***pseudo-code*** to demonstrate the concept, so ***not*** copy-paste worthy

**Activity A** - Pass in the boolean value that you want to the next activity

```
class ActivityA {

  private ListView listView

  onCreate() {
      listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter();
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener( new ItemClickListener() {

          onClick(int position) {
              MyData listObject = adapter.getItem(position);
              boolean checked = listObject.getCheck();

              Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
              i.putExtra("checkTheBox", check);

              startActivity(i);
          }

      });
    }
}
```

**Activity B** - Get the value out of the intent and set the checkbox to checked

```
class ActivityB {

    private Checkbox checkbox;

    onCreate() {

        checkbox = (Checkbox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            checkbox.setChecked(extras.getBooleanExtra("checkTheBox"));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why make a new account?

Comment: You are blocked by IP address, not account information. And the reason for blocking for asking too many questions (even if they are good) is because it shows you have not tried everything to fix the problem yourself. That includes researching errors and using excessive logging or a debugger for problematic code.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like implementing setOnclicklistner for checkbox. and assume an int variable to be zero. and when ever we click the checkbox increase the number by 1 every time. When we are moving from one activity to another send the data of int variable to Activity B. check Activity check the condition int variable as variable%2 if the value is equal to 1 the check box is checked. else it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the checked status for the selected list item when returning back from Activity B to Activity A.

In order to do that, you can simply store information in Activity A for the currently selected list item.

(for example `TreeMap<View, Boolean>` - item-> isSelected)

Then in onActivityResult you can set if there has been a check or not for the last selected item. When selecting again, before you create the intent you can check if this item has already been selected.

Answer (score 1):

To know ActivityA ListItem is checked in ActivityB (ie CheckBox) or not. Check this below code *hope this helps*

**ActivityA** stuff

```
int selectedPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //your UI setup and findViewById stuff

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedPosition = position;
            startActivityForResult(activityBIntent, REQ_CODE);
        }
    });

}


int REQ_CODE = 7;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            adapter.changeStatus(selectedPosition, true);//update adapter
        } else {
            //checkbox not checked
            adapter.changeStatus(selectedPosition, false);//update adapter
        }
}
```

**ActivityB** stuff

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //your UI stuff

    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);//default 
    //check box setup and save button onclick listener
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.save_button){
        if (checkBox.isChecked())
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
        else
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);//default
        finish();//finish ActivityB and take the result to ActivityA
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check my post again ?